# .aspectFill on NSImageView

Tags: swift, macos, nsimageview

I'm porting my SpriteKit app from iOS to MacOS. I am designing my main menu in the main.storyboard, and I have an image as the background. When I resize the window, however, my image does not fill the whole screen.

I've tried:

```
.scaleAxesIndependently //???
.scaleNone //Centre
.scaleProportionallyDown //???
.scaleProportionallyUpOrDown //AspectFit
```

but none are the same as `.aspectFill`.

I am using `swift`

Comment: There are so little new MacOS tutorials these days!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSImageView image aspect fill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002653/nsimageview-image-aspect-fill)

Comment: I needed clarification on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing `NSImageView` and overriding `intrinsicContentSize` you will be able to resizing image keeping aspect ratio, like so:

```
class AspectFillImageView: NSImageView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        guard let img = self.image else { return .zero }

        let viewWidth = self.frame.size.width
        let ratio = viewWidth / img.size.width
        return CGSize(width: viewWidth, height: img.size.height * ratio)
    }
}
```

If you just want to fill the whole view ignoring the ratio, use this extension instead:

```
extension NSImage {
    func resize(to size: NSSize) -> NSImage {
        return NSImage(size: size, flipped: false, drawingHandler: {
            self.draw(in: $0)
            return true
        })
    }
}
```

Extension usage:

```
NSImage.resize(to: self.view.frame.size)
```