# How do you adjust an image's size to NSImageView programmatically?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsimage, nsimageview

I have been trying to adjust an image's size in `NSImageView` programmatically. There doesn't seem to be any way to do so. The image ends up being quite large and there is no way to adjust it. I want to adjust it to a 40 (width) by 40 (height).

Here is the image view created programmatically:

```swift
let theImg: NSImageView = {
    let imageView = NSImageView()
    imageView.image = NSImage(named: "my-logo")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()
```

Here are the constraints for the image:

```swift
view.addSubview(theImg)
theImg.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 280).isActive = true
theImg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
theImg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
```

I'd appreciate those who would be willing to help or at least give some hints if possible.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002653/nsimageview-image-aspect-fill

Comment: So you want to adjust the size of the image to the size of the image view or do you want to adjust the size of the image view?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to your constraints like this:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theImg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 280),
            theImg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            theImg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50),
            theImg.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            theImg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])
```

`NSLayoutConstraint.activate` is a better approach to activate/deactivate constraints, because you can use an array of constraints and deactivate/activate them, instead of setting `isActive` one by one.

Also, unless you want your left/leading constraint to be on the left, even on right to left languages, you should use `leadingAnchor` instead of `leftAnchor`.
[More info](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/whats-the-difference-between-leading-trailing-left-and-right-anchors)